# Footer fixed at bottom doesn't allow content to show up complete

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues on my site and not know how to fix. I positioned the footer fixed to bottom (position: fixed, bottom:0) but now the middle content don't show complete. Why? Where is my mistake? This is the [site](http://comvivem.treswd.com/net/register)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this -

```
#main_content {
    margin: 15px auto;
    padding: 0 0 120px 0;
}
```

Your footer height is `100px` to cover that you need leave the same amount of space at bottom of `#main_content`

Comment: @dikpass see this: You can accept an answer in 2 minutes (click on this box to dismiss) so I'm waiting since you answer me to accept ;)

Comment: @ReynierPM If the header height is fixed you can do the same as - padding: 150px 0 120px 0;